# Do backholes decrease the entropy of universe to make entropy constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes

In a metabolic reaction, some amount of energy is always dissipated. Whether it's fusion or fission in case of an atomic reaction, energy is always released. So, can this energy be converted again to matter through black holes to make the universe entropy constant?

Comment: Despite the lore about this topic, gravitation doesn't lower entropy. When a gravitating mass collapses, it heats up and the heat and, depending on initial conditions, a substantial amount of the matter have to escape to infinity to satisfy both energy and angular momentum conservation. The escaping matter and radiation increases the total entropy.

Comment: It's not clear to me how black holes are supposed to "convert energy to matter", or why the universe's entropy should be constant.

Comment: Black holes are supposed to "convert energy to matter" because of its escape velocity and gravity, where photon cannot escape.

Comment: Why the universe's entropy should be constant? I have to give too many details for it to tell you why I think in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

Current measurements suggest we live in a Heat Death universe, so no.

Natural processes always tend to higher entropy in a closed system. Take the entire universe to be your closed system and it will become less and less "ordered" over time.

As for black holes contributing enough to counterbalance this - it's unlikely. Estimates are that there are a couple hundered million black holes in the Milky Way. That's 1/1000 the star count. Even on the small scale of entire galaxies, black holes don't do much in the scheme of things.

On the so-called "grand scale" -- no way are tiny little black holes of even $O(10^6)M_S$ going to effect the distribution of energy on the universal scale. Hubble's Law shows, in fact, that the opposite is true.

Comment: "As for black holes contributing enough to counterbalance this - it's unlikely. Estimates are that there are a couple hundred million black holes in the Milky Way. That's 1/1000 the star count. Even on the small scale of entire galaxies, black holes don't do much in the scheme of things." Don't you think we require less black holes to counter balance increase in entropy. E.g. through  formula E=MC^2 , we can convert lots of energy into matter.

Comment: Yes, but the energy density contribution of visible matter (such as black holes, ironically; as opposed to dark matter) is only about 5% of the total energy density of the universe.  The majority of all energy density in the universe is dark energy, accounting for 70% of the total density, and dark energy is what causes the accelerating expansion of the universe (i.e., a more entropic state).